# Which is the preferable design for my Gateway?

Tags: design-patterns, domain-driven-design

I'm writing a [Gateway class](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/gateway.html) that extracts information from a HTML document. One of the responsibilities of the class is to traverse a table in the document and extract data from its rows. I'm trying to decide how to best represent a row, and I've come up with two solutions (in semi-pseudo code).

I could represent each row as an associative array:

```
class Gateway
{

    private $crawler;

    public function __construct($crawler)
    {
        $this->crawler = $crawler;
    }

    public function getRows()
    {
        $this->crawler->xpath('...')->each(function($node, $i)
        {
            return [
                'someInfo'      => $node->xpath('...'),
                'someOtherInfo' => $node->xpath('...')
            ];
        });
    }

}
```

I could alternatively wrap each row in its own Gateway (however, I don't know if it's good practice to be hard-coding instantiation like this):

```
class Gateway
{

    private $crawler;

    public function __construct($crawler)
    {
        $this->crawler = $crawler;
    }

    public function getRows()
    {
        $this->crawler->xpath('...')->each(function($node, $i)
        {
            return new RowGateway($node);
        });
    }

}

class RowGateway
{

    private $crawler;

    public function __construct($crawler)
    {
        $this->crawler = $crawler;
    }

    public function getSomeInfo()
    {
        return $node->xpath('...');
    }

    public function getSomeOtherInfo()
    {
        return $node->xpath('...');
    }

}
```

Which is the preferable approach here? I'm open to other designs, too.

Answer (score 0):

I think that depends on how often RowGateway is going to be used in your application: if many parts of the application need to read that information, then creating a dictionary representation leaves you open to many field names that will need to be manually changed if you change you want to implement that object, and a real class would make more sense. However, if that information is going to be encapsulated by another class, or if the rest of the application is likely to call `Gateway->getRows()` directly, then you can probably get by with a dictionary as long as the documentation for `getRows()` clearly describes the dictionary in which each row will be returned.

One other change I'd make is to have RowGateway parse the rows on construction -- otherwise, a malformed row would not throw an error until someone tries to read that row, while I think it would be better to report that when loading the file.